# How to add a button into a recyclerview layout with cardview and adapter?

Tags: java, android, button, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add a button inside my recyclerview's cardview holder.

When the button is pressed, the user is directed to an external website when clicked.I also want to add multiple buttons to each cardview so that each button leads to a different website when clicked. How to do this?

My code:

Fragment class (i am using fragments):

```
public class BooksFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_books, container, false);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    ArrayList<exampleItemBooks> exampleList = new ArrayList<>();

    exampleList.add(new exampleItemBooks(R.drawable.thritysixstrategems, "The Thirty-Six Stratagems", "300 years ago, an unknown author compiled the Stratagems, a strangely seductive meditation on deception.", "-Unknown Author"));
    exampleList.add(new exampleItemBooks(R.drawable.medidations, "Meditations", "A book by the great Stoic Roman Emperor Marcus Aurelius. The book was written in Koine Greek, during the Emperor's reign.", "-Marcus Aurelius"));

    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewBooks);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    mAdapter = new exampleBooksAdapter(exampleList);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

}

Adapter:

```
public class exampleBooksAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<exampleBooksAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<exampleItemBooks> mExampleList;

public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView mImageView;
    public TextView mTextView1;
    public TextView mTextView2;
    public TextView mTextView3;

    public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewCards);
        mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCard1);
        mTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCard2);
        mTextView3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCard3);
    }
}

public exampleBooksAdapter(ArrayList<exampleItemBooks> exampleItemBooks) {

    mExampleList = exampleItemBooks;

}


@Override
public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item_books, parent, false);
    ExampleViewHolder evh = new ExampleViewHolder(v);
    return evh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {

    exampleItemBooks currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);

    holder.mImageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());
    holder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getText1());
    holder.mTextView2.setText(currentItem.getText2());
    holder.mTextView3.setText(currentItem.getText3());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mExampleList.size();
}
```

}

ArrayList class:

```
 private int mImageResource;
private String mText1;
private String mText2;
private String mText3;

public exampleItemBooks(int imageResource, String text1, String text2, String text3) {

    mImageResource = imageResource;
    mText1 = text1;
    mText2 = text2;
    mText3 = text3;

}

public int getImageResource() {

    return mImageResource;

}

public String getText1() {

    return mText1;
}

public String getText2() {

    return mText2;
}
public String getText3() {

    return mText3;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add a button to your viewholder layout and

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {

exampleItemBooks currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);

...  

holder.mButton.setTag("URL OF THE SITE");
holder.mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Take user to browser.
            }
});
```

}

Comment: But how do i make sure that each button directs the user to a different site and not just one website? Also do how do i link the button from my xml to the java class?

Comment: holder.mButton1.setTag("URL1");
holder.mButton2.setTag("URL2");

Create OnClickListeners to both buttons. You can get the url using v.getTag() inside OnClickListener. Each will goto the respective site.

Comment: You can link button the same way you did for the TextViews in your viewholder class. For eg: 

Button mButton1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mButton1);

Comment: do i have to use the Intent method in each onClickListener for each button so that it will launch the website? Or do i just have to just get.tag()?

Comment: It didnt work as i am using a cardview and not just a casual button. Also the getTag doesnt work :(